# What‘s the matter about CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am a newbie to CSS.Look at the pic:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9X6K.jpg

Why `img{border:2px,solid,red;}` on the right is line-through,and in the browser the image hasn't border.

Anybody can tell me the reason?

Answer (score 5):

Remove the commas because, your css statement is incorrect, hence the warning in the inspector:

```
img{border:2px solid red;}
```

Comment: Glad to help, would you mind choosing my answer as the correct solution please ? (Green tick).

Answer (score 5):

A strike through a css rule in a developer tool such as in chrome means the rule is not being applied. In your case this is because your css is invalid there shouldn't be commas i.e

```
img { border:2px,solid,red; } /* invalid css */ 

img { border: solid 1px red; } /* valid css */
```

this expands to all shorthand css rules i.e

```
p { margin: 0 10px 0 10px; }
```

It can also mean it is being overridden somewhere else you can use `!important` at the end of a declaration to force the style i.e

```
img { background: red !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove those commas and make your css like this

```
img {
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

multiple commas are used for define multi classes css.For more information check this [link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/cssselectors/f/comma-in-css-selectors.htm)